# closest method in phpQuery?

Tags: php, phpquery

I'm trying to see if there's a way to implement 
the "closest" method on phpQuery (just like it works on jQuery). 
Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Commonly Confused Bits Of jQuery](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/08/04/commonly-confused-bits-of-jquery/):

> #### CLOSEST(SELECTOR)
>
> This is a bit of a well-kept secret, but very useful. It works like parents(), except that it returns only one parent/ancestor. In my experience, you’ll normally want to check for the existence of one particular element in an element’s ancestry, not a whole bunch of them, so I tend to use this more than parents().

So as `parents()` exists in phpQuery you can go with the example from the source

> *Tip*: you can simulate closest() by using parents() and limiting it to one returned element.
>
> `$($('#element1').parents('#element2').get(0)).css('background', '#f90');`

Answer (score 0):

To actually spell out the phpquery syntax... (took me ages to get this!)

I wanted to extract the 'item' from an RSS feed that contained a specific enclosure (media file link).

```
function fetch($feed ,$fname)
{
    // load the file

    phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML($feed);

    // Find the first enclosure that links to the file
    // drill up to the parent elements to 'item' take the first (0)
    // this is the 'nearest' equivalent

    return pq("enclosure[url='" . $fname ."']:first")->parents('item')->xml();
}
```